# Keras plot_model() function: More elaborate output

Tags: python, keras

I'm using the Keras [plot_model() function](https://keras.io/visualization/) to visualize my machine learning models. Apart from having the issue that the first node of my output is always simply [a very large number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51717751/keras-plot-model-not-showing-the-input-layer-appropriately), there is another thing annoying me about this function: It does not provide a very elaborate output. For example, I would like to be able to see more information about the used loss function, the batch size, the number of epochs, the used optimizer, etc...

Is there any way I can retrieve this information from a model I previously saved to the disk and loaded again with the model_from_json() function?

Answer (score 1):

How about [TensorBoardCallback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard)? It will create interactive graphs that you can explore based on your model *if you use Tensorflow as your backend*.
[image]

You just need add it as a callback to your fit function and make sure `write_graph=True` is set (which it is by default). If you want a shortcut you can directly invoke its methods instead of passing as a callback:

```
tensorboard = TensorboardCallback()
tensorboard.set_model(model) # your model here, will write graph etc
tensorboard.on_train_end() # will close the writer
```

Then just run `tensorboard --logdir=./logs` to start the server.

Comment: Thank you for this useful hint. I'm indeed using TensorFlow as backend. Is there an easy way to export a TensorBoard to a (png) image?

Comment: It should be possible from the web interface, I can't remember right now.