# Keras Model Architecture

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I created the Keras model. Then I used a function that draws you a graph of the architecture of the model. It created png file that is shown below.

Code that creates a model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam', metrics=[self.coeff_determination])
```

Line that creates png image of the architecture:

```
plot_model(model, to_file='C:\CSV\model.png', show_layer_names=True, show_shapes=True)
```

This is the image I get:

[image]

The **question** is what the big number at the top of the graph means.

Comment: Question was edited

Comment: good job - downvote removed ;)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719035/1699882
Similar question?

Comment: Thank you @mirdad your comment helped me. I think I solved this problem. Obviously the problem is in sequential.py. Now I get this image: [link](https://i.imgur.com/ICUWOUP.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51719035/1699882). Check this link: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/10638

In keras/engine/sequential.py - Comment out the following code:

```
@property
def layers(self):
    # Historically, `sequential.layers` only returns layers that were added
    # via `add`, and omits the auto-generated `InputLayer`
    # that comes at the bottom of the stack.
    if self._layers and isinstance(self._layers[0], InputLayer):
        return self._layers[1:]
    return self._layers
```

Comment: As the answer to this question lies in that duplicate question, it is preferred that you do not post an answer, but flag to close this question as duplicate instead.